# performSegue not working FireBase while checking the user is authenticated Swift 3/4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, applet

I just finish a tutorial video of letsbuildthatapp about firebase mixed with social login.

I currently trying to perform a segue if the user is already authenticated.

I print something in my if and just after I performSegue with a segue who I know work because I'm using it for a test.

there is my code

```
func verifDejaConnecter() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueAccueilToPres", sender: nil)
        print("test")
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

mySegue is created and works but nothing append here.

In the console I can see the test resulting from the print in the if ... but nothing is mooving

Comment: where are you calling verifDejaConnecter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
func verifDejaConnecter() {
  if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueAccueilToPres", sender: self)
        print("test")
    }
  } else {
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice it works nicely I'm gonna try understanding what DispatchQueue.main.async does thanks a lot :)

Comment: It runs code on the main thread. You perform UI updates on the main thread always. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a different controller when opening the app if the User is logged in, I would suggest you instantiate a different controller...  Heres the code I'm using for this. (In AppDelegate)

```
if ((Auth.auth().currentUser) != nil)
    {
        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as! UITabBarController // or UIViewController depending on your setup.
    }
    else
    {
        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginController") as!
        LoginController // or your login controller.
    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

where "LoginController" & "tabBarController" you will need to input these into the storyBoard Identity inspector under Identity, StoryBoard  Identity.

Comment: Ok I got your idea thanks for helping me out David :)